# Issue importing JSON object into a MySQL column

Tags: python, mysql, json

I have created a Python script that creates a table in MySQL and another one that populates it with data from a JSON file.

## Sample JSON file:

```json
{
  "ansible_facts":{
    "ansible_network_resources":{
      "l3_interfaces":[
        {
          "name":"GigabitEthernet0/0"
        },
        {
          "name":"GigabitEthernet0/0.100",
          "ipv4":[
            {
              "address":"172.1.1.1 255.255.255.252"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name":"GigabitEthernet0/0.101",
          "ipv4":[
            {
              "address":"172.1.1.1 255.255.255.252"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name":"GigabitEthernet0/1",
          "ipv4":[
            {
              "address":"56.2.1.1 255.255.255.252"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name":"GigabitEthernet0/2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ansible_net_python_version":"3.6.9",
    "ansible_net_hostname":"host02342-mpls",
    "ansible_net_model":"CISCO-CHA",
    "ansible_net_serialnum":"F1539AM",
    "ansible_net_gather_subset":[
      "default"
    ],
    "ansible_net_gather_network_resources":[
      "l3_interfaces"
    ],
    "ansible_net_version":"15.3(2)T",
    "ansible_net_api":"cliconf",
    "ansible_net_system":"ios",
    "ansible_net_image":"flash0:/c3900-universalk9-mz.spa.153-2.t.bin",
    "ansible_net_iostype":"IOS"
  }
}
```

## Table creation script

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="IPaddress", user="user", password="pw", database="db")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Routers (ansible_net_hostname NVARCHAR(255), ansible_net_model NVARCHAR(255), ansible_network_resources NVARCHAR(255))")
```

## The script to import JSON data into MySQL

```
import json, pymysql

json_data = open("L3_out.json").read()
json_obj = json.loads(json_data)
con = pymysql.connect(host="IPaddress", user="user", password="pw", database="db")

cursor = con.cursor()
for item in json_obj:
    ansible_net_hostname = item.get("ansible_net_hostname")
    ansible_net_model = item.get("ansible_net_model")
    ansible_network_resources = item.get("ansible_network_resources")
    cursor.execute(
        "insert into Routers(ansible_net_hostname, ansible_net_model, ansible_network_resources) value(%s, %s, %s)",
        (ansible_net_hostname, ansible_net_model, ansible_network_resources)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

I'm having issues importing `ansible_network_resources` field object into the `Routers` table. The other columns (`ansible_net_hostname`, `ansible_net_model`) get inserted perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: you're missing a closing right round bracket - `)` - to close your `cursor.execute()` call in the second Python script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not clear how does

```
for item in json_obj:
    ansible_net_hostname=item.get("ansible_net_hostname")
```

work.
Since 'item' in your case is a key from the dictionary. In the file you shown there is only one root key "ansible_facts". So you are trying to call get() on the string.
To get the data of "ansible_network_resources" do the following:

```
for key in json_obj:
    ansible_network_resources=json_obj[key].get("ansible_network_resources")
```

Comment: Sir, getting an error by taking 'key' instead of 'item'

Comment: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json-to-mysql.py", line 9, in <module>
    ansible_network_resources=json_obj[key].get("ansible_network_resources")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict